# What is the best way to reuse query result sets from DB using PHP and include into phtml

Tags: php

i have a phtml site which has already the html layout like drop downs, tables, etc.

Now i want to fill a few of those elements with data coming from an Oracle database. So far i use PHP with below code snippet, but do i have to implement this piece of code for every item in the site or can I reuse the result set to implement it in different elements? Lets say I want to fill in Dropdown1, and i also want to list those items in Dropdown2 as well?

```
<?php
 $dbConnection = new DBController();

 $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $data["success"]["post_data"] = $request;

 $TestQuery = "SELECT ID, ITEM, NAME
              FROM SOME_TABLE
              WHERE ID = 'SOME_VALUE'
              ORDER BY ID ASC";

 $special_request_codes = array();
 $special_request_codes = $dbConnection->runQuery($TestQuery);

 if($test_query_result){
   $data["success"]["test_query_result"] = $test_query_result;
 } else {
   $data["error"]=array();
   $data["error"]["note_error_code"] = "get_test_query_result";
 }

echo JSON_ENCODE($data);

 ?>
```

Than I do an ECHO $data[1] to have a specific set of array value inside a i.e. Drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out mysqli_data_seek()

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

I think it's what you're looking for